# Trying to generate numbers and divide them down but they aren't dividing to the very end(Clarified)

Tags: python

Sorry I'm reposting but I wasn't clear at all at what I was trying to do so hopefully this helps

I'm trying to take any number that can turn into a simplified radical(x) and then turn it into 1 of the two parts of the simplified radical. I'm trying to take x which in the case is 248 and then turn it into the number outside the square root by dividing it until it can't be divided anymore.

I'm taking a big number like for the example 248, but the way I'm trying to do it is by dividing by whole numbers until I get to the smallest number but it isn't working and I've tried for a while figuring out what's wrong and I can't. I also am horrible at python because I just learned it so I'm kinda more or so messing around. Also, not decrementing I'm dividing to get a lower number. The problem is that it doesn't pick the next smaller number that it divided but instead sticks with what it had

```
import math
import random
import time
x = float(248)
k = int(1000)

while True:
    time.sleep(.00000000001)
    y = float(x / random.randint(1, (x-1))) #Selects numbers smaller than x and then divides it by itself
    g =(float(y).is_integer()) #Makes sure the divisions don't cause decimal numbers

    print(int(k)) #Just showing info

    if (bool(g)  == 1) and ( y <= (x/10)) :   #Checks if the divisions are small enough and if they are whole numbers
        if int(k) >= (x) :
            time.sleep(.1)  #Decides what numbers are small enough to divide
            if int(k) > (y) : #It also checks if the number it divided is smaller than the previous and if it is than it uses that instead, only problem is that it isn't doing that
                k = y
                print(int(k))
```

I'm trying to get the number 2(in this case) but it sometimes happens and sometimes its bigger.

Clarification: I'm trying to make a script that simplifies radical numbers and I should be getting 2 from 248.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You really need to design your algorithm before you start coding.  This has several problems that cause you trouble.

- This is a straight number theory application.  Quit using float.  You have the modulus operator to check divisibility.
- Flailing around with random numbers doesn't help.  Go through the integers in some methodical way.

You need to identify the largest integer whose square divides the given number.  This part is relatively simply, if you don't mind a brute-force approach.  I've used four test integers.

```
import math
for target in [248, 243, 700, 1001]:
    start = int(math.sqrt(target))
    for root in range(start, 0, -1):   # start with the largest possible root and work down.
        if target % (root*root) == 0:  # is the target divisible?
            break

    print target, "=", root, "sqrt", target / (root*root)
```

Output:

```
248 = 2 sqrt 62
243 = 9 sqrt 3
700 = 10 sqrt 7
1001 = 1 sqrt 1001
```

Comment: Yea like I said I'm a newbie at python and did not know the operator modulus(%) existed, That would have made everything so much easier.Sorry for looking up all of the operators I just knew most of them.